# pass username and password to sqoop meta connect from oozie

Tags: sqoop, oozie

```
<sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.3">
  <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <arg>job</arg>
      <arg>--meta-connect</arg>
      <arg>jdbc:mysql://FQDN:3306/sqoop</arg>
      <arg>--exec</arg>
      <arg>fabric_inventory</arg>
</sqoop>
```

Now, to pass username and password for the --meta-connect here,

if I pass it as following in oozie.xml:

```
<arg>jdbc:mysql://FQDN:3306/sqoop?user=sqoop&amp;password=sqoop</arg>
```

or

```
<arg>jdbc:mysql://FQDN:3306/sqoop?user=sqoop&password=sqoop</arg>
```

It gives following exception:

Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
2. it does not take

```
--username and --password prop and val in arg tag.
```

How do I pass the values in the correct manner?

This is what the complete exception looks like:

```
2016-05-11 10:21:44,920 ERROR [main] tool.ImportTool (ImportTool.java:run(613)) - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:177)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's a bit of confusion here... Oozie uses Sqoop**1** (original fat application, no server) and Sqoop1 optionally uses a Metastore but in **HSQLDB** -- no other databse is supported. On the other hand, there is Sqoop**2** (client/server evvolution) but *(a)* the development seems to be stalled and *(b)* Oozie does not support it.

Comment: Please read carefully the documentation https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html section 12, 13, 14.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever sort out the confusion between Sqoop**1** and Sqoop**2**, then you will have to jump over the Oozie hurdle too.

My advice: stop toying with command-line arguments and use standard Hadoop config files.

**1.** On your Gateway node (for unit tests), edit `/etc/sqoop/conf/sqoop-site.xml` to set Client properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- some stuff here that does not matter for Metastore -->
  ...

  <!-- now the Metastore config -->
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url</name>
    <value>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://FQDN:16000/sqoop</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.username</name>
    <value>sa</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.password</name>
    <value></value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.record.password</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**1b.** Upload that file to HDFS somewhere (for use with Oozie jobs)

**2.** On the node that will actually run the global Metastore DB, also edit the file, and also add two extra Server properties *(in this example the DB files are stored in `/var/lib/...`)*

```
  <property>
     <name>sqoop.metastore.server.port</name> 
     <value>16000</value> 
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>sqoop.metastore.server.location</name> 
     <value>/var/lib/sqoop/data/shared.db</value> 
  </property>
```

**2b.** Make sure you CHECKPOINT that database from time to time *(to reset the "script" file and flush the "redo log" file)* then backup the "script" file as a snapshot of the current DB state, somewhere safe, in case you lose the node and its disk -- yes, these things happen

**3.** In your Oozie Sqoop actions, set the Client properties with a `<job-xml>` entry targeting the config file in HDFS.

If you are interested in the actual Sqoop source code that handles these props and the Metastore client, look [there](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.5-cdh5.3.1/org/apache/sqoop/metastore/hsqldb/HsqldbMetaStore.java?av=f)

Answer (score 0):

**--meta-connect** should have value in  `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://<server-name>:<port>/sqoop` format(default is hsqldb).  You can change it to mysql in your case.

You can override below properties in sqoop-site.xml to pass the metastore username and password:

```
 <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.username</name>
    <value>SA</value>
    <description>The username to bind to the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.password</name>
    <value></value>
    <description>The password to bind to the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>
```

**--meta-connect** will read the username and password from here and will connect to the database.

You can refer the [default sqoop-site.xml](https://github.com/infinidb/sqoop/blob/master/conf/sqoop-site-template.xml) for more details