# sqoop fails to store incremental state to the metastore

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I get this on saving incremental import state

```
16/05/15 21:43:05 INFO tool.ImportTool: Saving incremental import state to the metastore
16/05/15 21:43:56 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Error communicating with database
at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.createInternal(HsqldbJobStorage.java:426)
at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.update(HsqldbJobStorage.java:445)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.saveIncrementalState(ImportTool.java:164)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:518)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:228)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:283)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.setV0Property(HsqldbJobStorage.java:707)
at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.createInternal(HsqldbJobStorage.java:391)
... 12 more
```

I have changed default metastore to MySQL. Everything else has been working just fine . I understand that some of the sources say that sqoop does not support it. In that case, I also need to know what is the default HSQL db url that I need to specify in --metaconnect argument?

In sqoop site.xml, I see that it is :

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:/tmp/sqoop-meta/meta.db;shutdown=true
```

But what do I specify in --meta-connect? I am sure this is not to be specified in there.

I need to specify meta-connect explicitly because I am running jobs through oozie and so will need to specify meta-connect.

I have checked and rechecked but nothing is running on port 16000. sqoop-metastore command can ofcourse start it but then it's not running as a service in that case.

so what I am asking is either a way to run sqoop metastore as a service or need to know why is this failing to store state in metastore when it is configured for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not *very* difficult to start a HSQLDB instance as a Linux service somewhere. Even if you stick to the obsolete V1.8 that is packaged with Sqoop1.

=> [Running Hsqldb (1.8) as a System Daemon](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/guide.html#N1075E)

Then you have to backup the data periodically => connect with JDBC client, run a [CHECKPOINT](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/guide.html#checkpoint-section), backup the "script" file that contains all SQL necessary to rebuild the DB snapshot.

Might be much easier than trying to hack a MySQL JDBC connection into [that source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.5-cdh5.3.1/org/apache/sqoop/metastore/hsqldb/HsqldbMetaStore.java?av=f) that expects HSQLDB.

Ah, and for no additional cost, you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153427/pass-username-and-password-to-sqoop-meta-connect-from-oozie/37162939#37162939) some explanations about how to use Java properties in the default conf files instead of command-line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem today with MySQL and found out why.

Sqoop locks himself out i guess by using different jdbc connections within the same process. By default, MariaDB (MySQL) creates table using the INNODB engine witch introduces transactions... I guess nobody tested Sqoop with INNODB.

All I did was to recreate the SQOOP_SESSIONS table in the metastore and used MyISAM engine.

```
CREATE TABLE `SQOOP_SESSIONS_n` (
  `job_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `propname` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `propval` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `propclass` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `SQOOP_SESSIONS_n_unq` (`job_name`,`propname`,`propclass`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

drop table SQOOP_SESSIONS;

rename table SQOOP_SESSIONS_n to SQOOP_SESSIONS;
```

Of course you wouldn't want to loose your created jobs if you had any. Just copy them BEFORE dropping the table:

```
insert into SQOOP_SESSIONS_n select * from SQOOP_SESSIONS;
```

Comment: I have been scouring the interwebs for 2 weeks looking for this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you error is on the mySQL side.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Can you send the complete command you used to run this.

Check the following in MySQL:-
show engine innodb status\G

You should consider increasing the lock wait timeout value for InnoDB by setting the innodb_lock_wait_timeout, default is 50 sec

show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';

you can set it to higher value in /etc/my.cnf permanently with this line

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
and restart mysql.

If you cannot restart mysql at this time, run this:

SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120; 
You could also just set it for the duration of your session

SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;