# Observing duplicates using sqoop with Oozie

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I've built a sqoop pogram in order to import data from MySQL to HDFS using a pre-built sqoop job:

```
                sqoop job -fs $driver_path -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris"\
            --create job_parquet_table -- import -m $nodes_number\
            --connect jdbc:mysql://$server:$port/$database --username $username --password-file $pass_file\
            --target-dir $destination_dir --table $table --as-parquetfile --append\
            --incremental append --check-column $id_column_names --last-value 1\
            --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \\ --enclosed-by '\"'
```

I've also builted a spark progam which permits to monnitore the sqoop importation. In this, I have measured the max_id (SELECT Max(ID) of the table which is being imported, the sqoop incremental.last.value, the number of records ( SELECT count(*)), the number of distinct records ( SELECT count(distinct ID)) and the percent of duplicates (defined as SELECT count(*) - count(distinct ID) / count(*) * 100).

When I import the data manually, by executing the sqoop job:

```
sqoop-job --exec job_parquet_$table -- --username edastatnew --password edastatnew
```

Everything is right, I've got no duplicates and data is perfectly imported

However, when I use Oozie to schedule the sqoop job, I have observed that sqoopincremental.last.value is wrongly updated, what causes duplicates in my data. Here is my monitoring:

[image]

As you can see, the max_ID doesn't match the sqoop_last_value at different time of the experiment. I have concluded that when using Oozie, the sqoop incremenatal.last.value is wrongly updated after executing a sqoop job.
Have someone faced this same issue? if yes, have you find any solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself a question: **where does Sqoop store that "last value" information?**

The answer is: for Sqoop1, by default, in a file on the *local filesystem*. But Oozie runs your Sqoop job on *random machines* therefore the executions are not coordinated.
And Sqoop2 (which has a proper Metastore database) is more or less in limbo; at least it is not supported by Oozie.

The solution is to start a **shared HSQLDB database service** to store the "last value" information for all Sqoop1 jobs, whatever machine they are running on.

Please read the Sqoop1 documentation about its lame [Metastore](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_metastore_literal) and about how to use it, from [there](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_saved_jobs) to [there](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_saved_jobs_and_incremental_imports).
And for a more professional handling of that obsolete HSQLDB database, look at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242857/sqoop-fails-to-store-incremental-state-to-the-metastore/37274484#37274484) of mine.