# Execute an previously created SQOOP job in HUE

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I have already created a SQOOP job using CLI

```
sqoop job \
--create spacex_import_job -- import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/spacex \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username root \
--password cloudera --table spacex_missions_w \
--hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table spacex.missions_inc -m 1 \
--check-column Record_TS --incremental lastmodified \
--last-value "2017-03-22 03:40:00"
```

And I am able to execute the job from CLI using following command:

```
sqoop job --exec spacex_import_job
```

Now, I want to execute the above command via OOZIE workflow on HUE. So I created a SQOOP action as

```
job --exec spacex_import_job
```

and tried executing. But got the following ERROR instead.

```
5238 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
5281 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.8.0
6015 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage  - Cannot restore job: spacex_import_job
6016 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage  - (No such job)
6018 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool  - I/O error performing job operation: java.io.IOException: Cannot restore missing job spacex_import_job
    at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.read(HsqldbJobStorage.java:256)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.execJob(JobTool.java:198)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:268)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:177)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: RTFM - by default, Sqoop stores the job information in a **local file** (using an embedded HSQL database), but that won't work with Oozie because it starts Sqoop on random nodes, not on the Edge Node where you have saved the job. So you have to launch a **Sqoop metastore service**, save your job there, and push some configuration in your Oozie job so that the Sqoop action connects to that Metastore instead of using a local file.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480188/observing-duplicates-using-sqoop-with-oozie and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242857/sqoop-fails-to-store-incremental-state-to-the-metastore and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153427/pass-username-and-password-to-sqoop-meta-connect-from-oozie

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thank you for you insight. And thanks for referring me to the above answers. Above answers seem slightly complicated so I think I'll have study more. I have been sick so I couldn't reply before.