# incremental import from sqoop job through oozie doesn't update incremental.last.value in sqoop's metastore

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

Trying to do incremental import from mysql to hive through creating sqoop job , it works fine from command line , but when i try the same with oozie , it doesn't update  incremental.last.value in sqoop's metastore

Comment: Share some code/scripts you are running

Answer (score 0):

RTFM: the official Sqoop documentation is [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html), and you should read carefully sections 12 *"Saved jobs"*, 13 *"sqoop-job"*, 14 *"sqoop-metastore"*.

I also wrote several SO answers on that topic, maybe more digestible for you that the raw docs:

- [what kind of Sqoop "metastore" you need with Oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480188/observing-duplicates-using-sqoop-with-oozie/37481491#37481491)
- [how to manage the "shared metastore" in a proper Linux service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242857/sqoop-fails-to-store-incremental-state-to-the-metastore/37274484#37274484), instead of the band-aid provided by Sqoop
- [how to pass "shared metastore" parameters to your Oozie action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153427/pass-username-and-password-to-sqoop-meta-connect-from-oozie/37162939#37162939)